# Flash Actionscript 3.0: 1010 Error...not sure what I have not defined, not external classes

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

**Program objective:** 
To create slideshow that imports images and audio via xml, using Timer class to automatically advance both images and audio after 1sec.

**What works:**
The images work perfectly, traversing the xml tree.

**What is broken:**
After third call, program throws this error?

TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at Chronic_fla::MainTimeline/playSong()
    at Chronic_fla::MainTimeline/timerListener()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

**My question:**
What is not defined? Do I have to explicitly declare something regarding my playSong function?
Or have I not imported a needed class?

Please help. I would greatly appreciated some insight.

Thanks!

**Code:**

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.utils.Timer;


var my_songs:XMLList;
var my_total:Number;
var my_sound:Sound;
var my_channel:SoundChannel;
var current_song:Number = 0;


var speed:Number;
var total:Number;
var images:XMLList;

var loaders_array:Array=[];
var labels_array:Array=[];
var success_counter:Number=0;
var playback_counter:Number=0;

var slideshow:Sprite = new Sprite();
var image_slides:Sprite = new Sprite();
var label_slides:Sprite = new Sprite();
var preloader:TextField;

var timer:Timer;
var prev_tween:Tween;
var tweens_array:Array=[];

var xml_loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xml_loader.load(new URLRequest("slideshow2.xml"));
xml_loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(event:Event):void
{
var xml:XML=new XML(event.target.data);
speed=xml.@SPEED;
images=xml.IMAGE;
//my_songs=xml.@URL;

total=images.length();

loadImages();

xml_loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
xml_loader = null;
trace(xml);
//trace(xml.children()[0].attribute("URL"));
//trace(xml.children()[0].attribute("TITLE"));
}

function loadImages():void {
for (var i:Number = 0; i < total; i++) {
    var url:String=images[i].@URL;
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    loaders_array.push(loader);

    var label:TextField = new TextField();
    label.text=images[i].@TITLE;
    label.autoSize=TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    labels_array.push(label);

    }

preloader = new TextField();
preloader.text="Loading";
preloader.autoSize=TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
    preloader.x = (stage.stageWidth - preloader.width)/2;
preloader.y = (stage.stageHeight - preloader.height)/2;
addChild(preloader);

}

function onComplete(event:Event):void {

success_counter++;
if (success_counter==total) {
    startShow();
    }

    var mloaderInfo:LoaderInfo=LoaderInfo(event.target);
mloaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

    }


function startShow():void {

removeChild(preloader);
preloader=null;

addChild(slideshow);
slideshow.addChild(image_slides);
slideshow.addChild(label_slides);

nextImage();

timer=new Timer(speed*1000);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
timer.start();

}

function nextImage():void {

var image:Loader=Loader(loaders_array[playback_counter]);
image_slides.addChild(image);
image.x = (stage.stageWidth - image.width)/2;
image.y = (stage.stageHeight - image.height)/2;
tweens_array[0]=new Tween(image,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,0,1,1,true);

var label:TextField=TextField(labels_array[playback_counter]);
label_slides.addChild(label);
label.x=image.x + 50;
label.y=image.y+image.height - 50;
label.border=true;
label.borderColor = 0x000000;
label.background=true;
label.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF;
label.textColor= 0xFF0000;
tweens_array[1]=new Tween(label,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,0,1,1,true);

}

function timerListener(event:TimerEvent):void {

hidePrev();

playback_counter++;
if (playback_counter==total) {
    playback_counter=0;
}
nextImage();

current_song++;

if (current_song==my_songs.length) {
    current_song=0;
}
else if (current_song!= 0) {
    playSong(current_song++);
}
}


function hidePrev():void {

var image:Loader=Loader(image_slides.getChildAt(0));
prev_tween=new Tween(image,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,1,true);
prev_tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFadeOut);

var label:TextField=TextField(label_slides.getChildAt(0));
tweens_array[2]=new Tween(label,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,1,true);

}

function onFadeOut(event:TweenEvent):void {
image_slides.removeChildAt(0);
label_slides.removeChildAt(0);
}


var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("playlist.xml"));
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processMXML);

function processMXML(e:Event):void {
var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

my_songs = myXML.SONG;
my_total = my_songs.length();

playSong(my_songs.length);

myXMLLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processMXML);
myXMLLoader = null;
trace(myXML);
}

function playSong(mySong:Number):void {
//var myTitle = my_songs[mySong].@TITLE;
//var myArtist = my_songs[mySong].@ARTIST;
var myURL = my_songs[mySong].@URL;

//title_txt.text = myTitle;
//artist_txt.text = myArtist;

if (my_channel) {
    my_channel.stop();
    //my_channel.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onNext);
}

my_sound = new Sound();
my_sound.load(new URLRequest(myURL));
my_channel = my_sound.play();
//my_channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onNext);
}
```

Comment: It could possibly be that your are trying to access a song in `my_songs` that is out of bounds? You do `playSong(my_songs.length);
`. The array starts at 0 which means `my_songs.length` should probably be `my_songs.length - 1`.

Comment: First,thank you very much for your insight. I tried it but to no avail. Outputs a "SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context."
I explicitly define my_total as a Number and cast it as  my_songs.length()which should begin at a value of 0 initially?

Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the timerListener() method, you're incrementing the current_song variable 2 times, so you're probably getting an index out of bounds error in playSong().

```
 function timerListener(event:TimerEvent):void {

    hidePrev();

    playback_counter++;
    if (playback_counter==total) {
       playback_counter=0;
    }
    nextImage();

    current_song++;

    if (current_song==my_songs.length) {
         current_song=0;
    }
    else if (current_song!= 0) {
         playSong(current_song); // that's where you incremented current_song again
    }
 }
```

Comment: First and foremost, thank you for your added insight.
The first increment is just to have it play but I thought with the else if statement that it would only increment a second time, if and only if, the current song was anything other than 0?

This didn't work! It cast the same error after 8calls?
    else if (current_song!= 0) {
  playSong(current_song++);
 }

But from your perspective response, I change one thing and bingo!

Somehow, this did the trick! Traverses the entire xml tree without a single error.
 else if (current_song!= 0) {
  playSong(current_song+1);
 }
Awesome! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Just so you know, you can go into Publish Settings and tick "Permit Debugging". This will then give you line numbers for where your errors are, making it much easier to find these issues.

Answer (score -2):

Quite easy really, typed variable would throw a null error, untyped variables throw an undefined error. Look for the untyped variables in that function:

```
var myURL
```

Only one I see that can be undefined.
Turn it into:

```
var myURL:String
```

And you should get a null error instead.

How come all your other variables are typed and not this one? What's so special about this one that you decide to not type it?

Comment: First and foremost, thanks for your help. You're exactly right I should have explicitly declare the data type. At times, I'm guilty of forsaking the all-powerful yet lowly String!
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: voting down without any explanation is not better. Shame on you both.